# Ubuntu: Virtual devices in Android studio

Tags: android, ubuntu, kotlin

I want to learn Kotlin but I can't. I'm using Kubuntu 20.04 (with NVIDIA GeForce GT 710 graphic card and nvidia-driver-455 driver). I can open virtual device after I create new project. But device is empty and there is not started Android. I see only black page or graphic of other opened window: [Screenshot of Virtual device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DOdR.png)

I see only "Loading devices" in Android studio when I import this project from GitHub: https://gist.github.com/vishnuharidas/33c95afb49ebe9c2dd3c65b5b13d534d

There stays no devices when I create configuration.
And virtual devices are empty when I cloned some another project from GitHub.

I see only "Unable to locate adb" when I open Android Virtual Device Manager.

It writes error "Module not specified" when I created configuration. There is not option File > New > New Module".

I tried reinstall Android studio many times.

Or I can test my apps in real mobile phone but I don't know how.

I finded some similar questions but nothing works for me. Can someone help me?

I tried it in Windows in VirtualBox with same error: Unable to locate adb.

Comment: Just enable USB debugging on your device then plug it into your computer. Android Studio should detect it.

Comment: Yes, I've got USB debugging enabled (I followed this settings: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device) but I don't see my device in list of devices.

Answer (score 0):

I know the reason, I think. I tried Intellij and there was an error about my CPU: Host CPU is missing the following feature(s) required for x86 emulation: SSSE3. So I tried Intellij and Android studio in my notebook with SSSE3 in CPU. It works! I see the virtual device with Android. There's some warnings/errors too but I'll try to solve these.

Finally solution: check your processor: `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep ssse3`

Answer (score 0):

I found another problem . My USB connector in my PC worked little bad. So check your USB too if you've got a same problem. "real emulator" (my mobile phone) works right now. Procesor without SSSE3 is not a problem in this case.